# Pandas - Efficient storing of (row,column,values) for sparse matrices

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sparse-matrix

I am using the following function to calculate similarity indices of objects saved in a list. I want to produce a matrix that has objects names on rows and columns, with cell values  indicating similarity scores. I am now using this code:

```
obj = [o1, o2, o3]
names = ["o1","o2","o3"]

results = pd.DataFrame(columns= names)

for i,o in enumerate(obj):
    simdict = {}
    for k in range(i+1, len(obj)):
        simdict[names[k]] = similarity(o, obj[k])
    row = pd.DataFrame([simdict], columns=simdict.keys())
    results = pd.concat([results, row], ignore_index=True)
results.index = names
```

The result is like this one:

```
    o1      o2      o3
o1  NaN     0.5     1.0
o2  NaN     NaN     0.3
o3  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

My problem is that when the list of objects is huge, the process gets very slow, probably due to the `pd.concat()` function.

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to store similarity scores (maybe in a dict or list of triplets) and then convert them to a matrix (as a pandas df). Probably avoiding `pd.concat()` in a loop.

In my example, I am not repeating symmetrical values (I just show the upper triangle of the matrix), but this can also change if needed.

Comment: `results = []` at the top, `results.append(row)` in the loop and `pd.DataFrame(results)` at the end. Don't do concats in a loop it's a full copy of all your data every iteration.

Comment: How sparse is this matrix? In the given example, the upper triangle of the matrix is filled, so for large matrices 50% of matrix will be filled. As a rule of thumb, sparse matricies only save space if less than 1/3 of your values are filled. Does your real problem have more sparse values?